# Cancelar una corrutina en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, corrutinas, android-corrutinas

tengo una inquietud relacionada con programación en Kotlin y las corrutinas...
Resulta que tengo que hacer varias validaciones y algunas dependen entre sí, es decir, si un endpoint devuelve una respuesta se hace algo y si no se hace otra cosa...
El problema que tengo es que el tiempo de ejecución de mi corrutina funciona sólo si yo doy un tiempo estático y me gustaría que cuando tenga respuesta el "Delay" que estoy usando se "cancele"
Ejemplo
1 request funciona si le doy 5 segundos
y dependiendo de la velocidad del internet y los procesos se podría tardar mucho menos
imaginen si en cada proceso se debería tardar 2 segundos y tenemos 10 procesos
Escenario Ideal: 2 segundos por cada petición x 10 peticiones = 20 segundos de procesamiento
Escenario que tengo: 5 segundos por cada petición x10 peticiones = 50 segundos de procesamiento
Creo que hay mucha diferencia entre estos casos y me gustaría implementar el escenario ideal.
Gracias a todos por leerme

EJEMPLO EN CODIGO

```
  viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            // PETICION DE API 
            procesamiento()
            suspend {
                delay(5000)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                 // AL TERMINAR EL PROCESO
                  if(respuestaDeProceso){
                      // RESPONDIO TRUE
                  } else{
                     // RESPONDIO FALSE
                  }
                }
            }.invoke()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario que metas `delay` artificiales para esperar a que esté listo un resultado. Las corotuines funcionan de tal manera que puedes escribir el código como si fuera secuencial y se comportará como tal.

Si necesitas procesamiento secuencial no hace falta que inicies corotuines porque lo puedes manejar con funciones suspendibles:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    // PETICION DE API
    val respuestaDeProceso = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        procesamiento()
    }

    if (respuestaDeProceso) {
        // RESPONDIO TRUE
    } else {
        // RESPONDIO FALSE
    }
}
```

Si necesitas llamar a `procesamiento` creando otro subproceso y suponinendo que no necesitas que te retorne nada pero sí necesitas esperar a que se complete, entonces inicias otra coroutine con `launch` y usas el `Job` que te devuelve para esperar a que termine llamando a su función `join`:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    // PETICION DE API
    val job = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        procesamiento()
    }
    
    job.join()//Espera a que termine la coroutine
        ...
}
```

O si se da el mismo caso anterior pero sí necesitas que te retorne algún dato entonces inicias otra coroutine con `async` y esperas por el resultado llamando a la función `await` del `Deferred` que te devuelve:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    // PETICION DE API
    val respuestaDeProceso = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        procesamiento()
    }

    if (respuestaDeProceso.await()) {//Continúa hasta que la coroutine finalice y extrae el resultado
        // RESPONDIO TRUE
    } else {
        // RESPONDIO FALSE
    }
}
```

Como observación toma en cuenta que cuando creas una coroutine con `lifecycleScope`, ésta se ejecuta sobre el hilo principal, por lo tanto no necesitas esta instrucción `withContext(Dispatchers.Main){...}`. Si necesitas un "sub-ámbito" para ejecutar ese bloque, usa `coroutineScope {...}` en su lugar o `supervisorScope {...}` según sea tu caso de uso. Si necesitas cambiar de `Dispatcher` entonces sí puedes usar `withContext`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme hace rato hice pruebas de este modo pero no conseguí que mi petición del lado de la función "procesamiento" devolviera algo de manera asíncrona y aún tengo esa inquietud porque me quedan claros los bloques de código pero sigo sin entender cómo debo armar una petición asíncrona para gestionarla con . await ()

Comment: @AntonioLabra Creí que lo que necesitabas era eliminar el `delay` y actuar tan pronto `procesamiento` finalizara. Para que `procesamiento` sea asíncrono debes ejecutarlo dentro de una nueva coroutine (`async(Dispatchers.IO){...}`). Para que devuelva algo basta con poner el resultado en la última línea del bloque. Extraes el resultado llamando a `await`. Mi tercer ejemplo se ajusta a lo que quieres.